# Consider a Cauchy-Euler ODE $t^2y''+\alpha ty'+\beta y=0$ and using the variable change $x_1=y, x_2=ty'$ find the matrix that solves the system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a Cauchy-Euler ODE $t^2y''+\alpha ty'+\beta y=0$ and using the variable change $x_1=y, x_2=ty'$ find the equivalent first order system. Prove that the matrix that solves the system is $R(t,\tau)=\exp(\ln(t/\tau)A)$ where A is a matrix you have to identify.

So for the first part I got:

$\begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}=$
$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1/t \\ -\beta/t&(1-\alpha)/t\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$

but I don't know how tho see the second part. I guess it must be related with the change of variable $t=e^\tau$ but I don't know how to that.

Comment: how comes the solution given depend on two variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1/t \\ -\beta/t&(1-\alpha)/t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}=\frac 1 t
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1  \\ -\beta &(1-\alpha)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Substitute $t=e^{\tau} \implies \tau = \ln t$
$$x'_1=\frac {dx_1}{dt}=\frac {dx_1}{d\tau}\frac {d\tau}{dt}=\frac {1}{t}\frac {dx_1}{d\tau}$$
$$x'_2=\frac {dx_2}{dt}=\frac {dx_2}{d\tau}\frac {d\tau}{dt}=\frac {1}{t}\frac {dx_2}{d\tau}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x'_1(\tau) \\ x'_2(\tau )\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1  \\ -\beta &1-\alpha\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1(\tau) \\ x_2(\tau)\end{pmatrix}$$
Now the Matrix A has constant coefficients and the system can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$x_2'=ty''+y'=-αy′-βy/t+y'=(1-α)/t\cdot x_2-β/t\cdot x_1,$$ so you got the composition of the lower right matrix entry wrong, and also missed the division by $t$ there. In total, you can extract the factor $1/t$ from the matrix, leaving you with a constant matrix where you can now proceed with the substitution $t=e^s$.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm having trouble with the substitution, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Set $u_k(s)=x_k(e^s)$, then $u_k'(s)=x_k'(e^s)e^s=tx_k'(t)$. The rest follows.